# Display panda crosstab as a table

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

Is there any way to show panda cross tab as a clean table?
I use tabulate and it's not like what I want.

```
input : print(tabulate(pd.crosstab(y_test,y_pred)))

output:
-  --  --
2  71  23
3  20  74
-  --  --
```

I need some clean output like what Jupyter notebook generate:
[image]

Thanks in advance